# C++11 Automate creation of integer to enum value map

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, enums

I need to create a map of `int` to `enum` values. (I'm reading integers in a file and need to create an `enum` from them at runtime.) I can manually create a map as shown in my example below. However this is a trivial example with only a few (i.e., seven) elements of my enum.

My real-world-problem has several hundred elements of my `enum class`. I don't need to print the names of my real-world `enum`, but I do need to get the `enum` value given an integer. I already have the `enum class` created and want an automatic way to create a map from an integer to the enum value.

**I'm looking to automate the creation of the map which I've called `WeekMap` so I can pass it an integer and get the `enum` value.** Is this even possible? Please tell me it is.

```
// Compile with:
//      clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ enum_test.cpp -o enum_test
// 

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

enum class Days {
    SUNDAY    = 1,
    MONDAY    = 2,
    TUESDAY   = 3,
    WEDNESDAY = 4,
    THURSDAY  = 5,
    FRIDAY    = 6,
    SATURDAY  = 7
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Days& day){
    os << static_cast<std::underlying_type<Days>::type>(day);
    return os;
}

std::map<unsigned int, Days> WeekMap{
    {1, Days::SUNDAY},
    {2, Days::MONDAY},
    {3, Days::TUESDAY},
    {4, Days::WEDNESDAY},
    {5, Days::THURSDAY},
    {6, Days::FRIDAY},
    {7, Days::SATURDAY},
};

// Return the day of the week
Days WhatDay(unsigned int D){
    return WeekMap[D];
}

int main() {

    std::cout << "\nLearning how to 'cout' enums." << std::endl;

    Days myDay = Days::MONDAY;

    std::cout << "\nMonday is day: " << myDay << "\n" << std::endl;

    for (int i=1; i<8; i++){
        std::cout << "Day number: " << i << " is " << WhatDay(i) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't `WhatDay` just do `return static_cast<Days>(D)`?

Comment: Are the values of elements in your `enum` contiguous?  Do you need error checking for invalid values?

Comment: Yes, WhatDays can return `static_cast<Days>(D)`. This is just an example. What I really need to do is get the enum value given an integer; i.e., given a `2`, I need `Days::MONDAY`.

Comment: @Yakk The values are not continuous, error checking is not strictly needed, but would be nice.

Comment: `static_cast<Days>(2) == Days::MONDAY`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not need the `map`. Your `WhatDay` function can be written like this:

```
Days WhatDay (unsigned int D) {
    return static_cast<Days>(D);
}
```

This is basically free (in efficiency terms.) But you might want to make sure your `enum`'s underlying type is indeed an `int` (or something smaller or larger;) again for efficiency reasons and for reliability reasons:

```
enum class Days : int {
    ...
};
```

What you will lose, however, with this method is error checking. You won't be able to check whether the integer is a valid enumeration value or not; especially if your enum values are not contiguous.

**UPDATE 2** (Update 1 is below!)
To somewhat automate creation of this kind of `enum`, and a whole lot of other code, you can use the following technique:

You first write down the data you are interested in, in a general format:

```
#define EXPAND_VALUES(action)           \
    action (1, SUNDAY,    "Sunday")     \
    action (2, MONDAY,    "Monday")     \
    action (3, TUESDAY,   "Tuesday")    \
    action (4, WEDNESDAY, "Wednesday")  \
    action (5, THURSDAY,  "Thursday")   \
    action (6, FRIDAY,    "Friday")     \
    action (7, SATURDAY,  "Saturday")
    // Note the lack of a separator after the entries; this is more flexible.
```

This is all the information I have about each of the entries, in a general form (i.e. passed to an unknown function-like *thing* called `action`.

Now, to define the enumeration, we can simply say:

```
#define DEF_ENUM(i,v,s) v = i,
enum class Days : int { EXPAND_VALUES(DEF_ENUM) };
#undef DEF_ENUM
```

As further examples, you can define the map you want, and another table that maps `enum` values to strings like this:

```
#define DEF_MAP(i,v,s)  {i, Days::v},
std::map<int, Days> WeekMap { EXPAND_VALUES(DEF_MAP) };
#undef DEF_MAP

#define DEF_STR_MAP(i,v,s)  {Days::v, s},
std::map<Days, std::string> WeekStrMap { EXPAND_VALUES(DEF_STR_MAP) };
#undef DEF_STR_MAP
```

(This sample code is [available on Ideone](http://ideone.com/TofKm6).)

Note what this technique does for you. Without any redundancy in data definition, you get as many data-structure definitions, array initializations, `switch`-statement cases, `if`-`else if`-`else` constructs, etc. you want out of that data. And all of this is done at compile time (or before) without any hassles.

This is an extremely powerful technique that might (or might not) be useful to you.

---

**UPDATE 1** (In response to the updated question):

No, it is not possible to create an `enum` at runtime in C++. You cannot create a new type for the compiler at runtime, when there is no more compiler (if this is really what you're after.)

However, since `enum`s in C++ offer absolutely no runtime facilities, then, at runtime, there is no difference between two `enum`s with the same underlying type. Or in fact, between an `enum` and an `int` (if `int` is the underlying type for that `enum`.)

Therefore, I propose this: you define an *empty* `enum`, and write the `WhatDay` function exactly as before. And everything will be fine! (Since you don't need bounds checking.)

Specifically, what I'm proposing is this:

```
enum class Days : int { /*really, really empty!*/ };

Days WhatDay (unsigned int D) {
    return static_cast<Days>(D);
}
```

This works because it seems to me that *you do not know your enumeration values at compile time*, and the compiler doesn't care one bit for the values of an `enum` at runtime. No one does!

And if you want error and range checking, I suggest you use an "*Interval Tree*" ([read up on it on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).) You populate this tree when you read your `enum` values from your file at runtime (and this is the only data structure you populate,) and then check each value passed to the `WhatDay` function against it.

Comment: Well, this would work, but in the end I'm not looking to print out the integer value. I'm looking for the `enum` value given an integer value. I've updated my question to address this confusion.

Comment: @Jeremy reread this answer.  It produces the `enum` value from the `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Jeremy: I expanded the answer quite a bit. I suggest you have a look at the updates.

Comment: @yzt The second edit is exactly what I needed. It's really great!

Comment: @yzt Now that I've begun playing with this, I love it even more. I'm new to doing anything with the preprocessor. Can I define `DEF_ENUM` so I can use it to create multiple `enum`s, just starting with different values?

Comment: @Jeremy: You mean like having a `Days1` enum that starts with `SUNDAY = 1` and another `Days4` that starts with `SUNDAY = 4`?

Comment: @yzt No. Suppose I want a `Days` enum and a `Months` enum. I want to create an enum and a map for `Months` just like I did for `Days`. Can I do this without duplicating macros?

Comment: @Jeremy: Note that the `DEF_*` macros aren't exactly meant to be reused (except maybe the most primitive and simple ones; or the most complex and "ubermacro"ey ones.) For this reason, I simply advise you to define `DEF_ENUM` to things like `v = (i)+3,` or `v = 1 << (i),` or the like.

Comment: My recommendation, again, is to duplicate the one-liner macros and don't obsess too much about them! Think of them like lambdas (the macro equivalent of lambdas.) You don't bother yourself much with having to rewrite a bunch of similar one-line lambdas, right?

Comment: Also, since you cannot emit `#define` directives in the expansion of a macro, your ability to write higher-order macros is severely limited. (Have a look at e.g. Boost.Preprocessor though, if you are interested in some pretty advanced macro magic!)